# Mail and iCloud with other email accounts

Tags: apple-mail, icloud

In my macbook (OS X Lion) I use Mail app with a work email account (non gmail or apple, or yahoo, etc). I would like to use iCloud for syncing email incoming and sent between iPad and macbook, but it seems you can only use it with mobile me accounts. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: You can only sync emails on multiple devices if teh email account is an IMAP emal account, it sounds like you have a POP mail account. If you are able to you could chnage the settings to enable IMAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward the incoming mail from the other accounts to your @me account.

If one is for work you could also create another @me account and set up that account to receive the forwarded emails from the other accounts.

Comment: I do not have me account, is it free?

Comment: Forward the email from your Google, Hotmail, or yahoo account. The ICloud is what apple is calling the old mobile me.

Comment: yes you can sign up for your own @me account. It will be your iTunes account and password if you want it to be.

Comment: Have you had any luck? Check this link out as well....https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3102165?start=0&tstart=0